# Ordenar uma LinkedList de inteiros sem método sort?

Tags: java, lista

quero saber um método simples para ordenar uma LinkedList! Estou quebrando a cabeça e revirando a internet, porém só acho métodos que já realizam o trabalho que eu **GOSTARIA** de realizar manualmente.

```
   public class OrdenacaoTeste {

    public static void ordenaLista(LinkedList<Integer> lista) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> lista = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        lista.add(1);
        lista.add(5);
        lista.add(3);
        lista.add(6);
        lista.add(8);


        System.out.println("lista não ordenada: " + lista);

        Collections.sort(lista); //ordena automaticamente
        System.out.println(lista);

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lista.size() - 1; j++) {

         }
      }



    }
}
```

Minha classe recebe os valores, 1, 5, 3, 6, 8! Eu sei como funciona uma lista ligada, então estou utilizando o linkedlist para poupar trabalho! **Porém como eu posso como um laço for e talvez condições IFS ordenar a lista em ordem crescente?**

Sei que para ordenação terei de fazer ifs para comparação do maior e menor, porém queria ajuda de como passar esses valores e como trabalhar com os mesmos nessa mesma classe.

Desde já grato.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19263295/5524514

Comment: não vejo a forma de como este modo vai auxiliar-me a realizar a tarefa de forma manual?!

Comment: Sua pergunta da a entender que você quer fazer manualmente. Se não é isso que deseja, sugiro edita-la e deixar o que deseja fazer mais claro.

Comment: Acredito que a pergunta esteja bem claro, desculpe por algum inconveniente, quero apenar ordenar os valores dessa lista de uma forma crescente e manual. Exemplo, se fosse um vetor de 5 posições, eu faria dois for's e um if(vet[j] > vet[j + 1]){
     aux = vet[j];
     vet[j] = vet[j+1];
     vet[j+1] = aux;
    }.

Comment: Entendi, acho que essa aqui vai te atender certinho http://stackoverflow.com/a/6369923/5524514

Comment: Obrigado @diegofm pela paciência e comentários!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui galera, creio que o código é simples e auto suficiente de explicações

Também deixo meu muito obrigado ao @diegofm, você é fod4!

```
public class OrdenacaoTeste {
public static void ordenaLista(LinkedList<Integer> lista) {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> lista = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    lista.add(8);
    lista.add(9);
    lista.add(3);
    lista.add(5);
    lista.add(1);

    System.out.println("lista não ordenada: " + lista);

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size() - 1; i++) { // percorro
        for (int j = 0; j < lista.size() - 1; j++) {
            if (lista.get(j) > lista.get(j + 1)) { // vejo se é maior que a
                                                    // prox posiçao
                Integer maior = lista.get(j);
                Integer menor = lista.get(j + 1);

                lista.remove(maior);
                lista.remove(menor);
                lista.add(j, menor);

                lista.add(j + 1, maior);
                // lista.remove(i);
            }
        }
        // Utilizando SORT
        // Collections.sort(lista);
        //System.out.println("Utilizando método sort" + lista);

        System.out.println("Lista ordenada em ordem crescente: " + lista); //imprimindo dentro do for
    }
    // System.out.println("Lista ordenada em ordem crescente" + lista); 
}
```

}

Comment: Ah, você queria uma ordenação estilo [bubble sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)? Eu havia entendido que era implementar seu sort manualmente ao inves de usar o da Collections, mas que bom que conseguiu resolver =)